# Server side single quote breaking javascript string

Tags: c#, javascript, jqplot

I have a server side variable

```
string test = "test";
ticks = "['" + test + "']";
```

I am setting ticks to a hidden field on the page but when I try to get the value in javascript the single quote is breaking the string and all i am getting from it is [.
Is there a way around this?

I am using c# 3.

Thanks

Comment: The way around it would be to omit the single quotes in the value of the hidden field.

Comment: I need the single quotes though. I am using a graphing plugin that needs values in the format of ['a','b','c']

Comment: Then you can either: Escape the single quotes, emit java-script from code-behind instead of a hidden field or construct the correct variable in javascript using the hidden field, without the single quotes.

Comment: how are you accessing it from your javascript or assigning it to your hiddenfield - I just tried it and it works??

Comment: @codingbiz I am first assigning it to a hidden field and then reading the value of the hidden field. Its when I read it, the problem occurs

Comment: I had no problem with it. I just did that. Post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of forming your string manually, use a json parser

```
string js = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new[]{"a","b","c"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your test value with '\''

Comment: have you looked at the value with firebug or other client debugger tools?